# Correct way to move between fragments to correct use the back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to move from activity A to activity B, and there, move to A again.

A is the parent activity, defined in android.manifest in that way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.map.view.AActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

While B is defined like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.addwifi.view.BActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

I use this call to move from A to B:

```
public void openBActivity(UserData user) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(BActivity.SSID, BActivity.getWifi_ssid().replace("\"", ""));

    if (user != null) {
        intent.putExtra(BActivity.LATITUDE, user.getLatitude());
        intent.putExtra(BActivity.LONGITUDE, user.getLongitude());
        intent.putExtra(BActivity.ZOOM_LEVEL, (int) user.zoom);
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And from B to A:

```
public void openAActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpotsMapActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem is when I press back in A, it moves to another Activity A not exiting the app. What I want to do is to move from A to B, next from B to A and from A to exit (pressing back button).

[image: Activity navigation flow]

I have read [Google docs about back navigation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you are working with Activity here and no fragments are being used. Maybe you can use Fragments(?) as then when you press Back, you are basically exiting from the Activity (if you're not adding Fragments to the BackStack). That will give you the behavior you need.

With you're current implementation you need to exit from the app when you press back from Activity B correct? In this case, you need to close out Activity A when you move away from it to B. A simple call to finish() method will do it. Put it after the startActivity(intent) call:

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This should close out Activity A and then start B. This is kind of like a brute shut down of A. To make it elegant, just make sure you close out any resources A may be hanging on to in order to avoid leaking.

Just as a side note, Android's expected behavior when you start a new Activity is to put the other Activity in a stopped state but still in the Activity stack. Since you are moving away from Android's design principle, maybe a Fragment may suit your need better - I don't know what exactly you are trying to do but I strongly encourage people to reconsider before moving away from Android's design.

**EDIT**

It looks like you are starting Activity A again from B when you are exiting B - it's not required actually. Android will retain the previous instance of A which is why you are seeing another instance of A when you go back

Comment: I have used your idea to call finish() but I think it is not the best way to do it because I am not ordering the back stack correctly, just finishing a activity.

Comment: Oh.. I think I see the problem now - When you start Activity A from B again, you are actually creating a new instance of Activity A - that is why you see another instance of A in the activity stack. It looks like you are overriding the onBackPressed() (or possibly onDestroy()) method in Activity B to start Activity A. Is that correct? You do not have to start a new instance of A - Android will retain the previous instance of the Activity A in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the FLAGS. I think it is the most elegant way.

public void openAActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SpotsMapActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK + Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}